# Why paper overrides my custom html divs (joint js)?

Tags: html, jointjs

I have this html:

```
<div class='paper-container' id="wrapper">
    <div class='paper' id="paper" style='margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right: 0px;'>
        <div id='linkMenu'>
          <ul id='linkMenu-items'>
            <li class='contextOption' name='deleteLink'>Delete link</li>
            <li class='contextOption' name='showStart'>Show link start</li>
            <li class='contextOption' name='showEnd'>Show link end</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After application renders and reach this point,

```
 var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $("#paper"),
        width: PAPER_WIDTH,
        model: graph,
        ...
   )};
```

- Before rendering:

[image]]

- After rendering:
  [image]
- I don't have the possibility to catch the div of contextmenus for the
  links after the application renders.
- It seems that joint js overrides    my html with its own.
- I am using    the 0.9.6 version and I want to    upgrade the version
  to the last    one.

  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For anyone facing this problem, I will suggest another solution which is to move the div out of scope of the paper and append it based on its action.

```
paper.$el.append($('#linkMenu'));
```

- For more details please click the link below:

https://github.com/clientIO/joint/issues/1212